# posting to Facebook Feed when comment is added to a website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a Facebook App and a Facebook Page for a company. What I want to do is to trigger an event whenever someone adds a facebook comment on that company's website. This event will copy the comment and posts it to the company's Facebook Page (using the Facebook App). The name and the photo of the user who posts to the facebook page shouldn't be the original user, instead it will be replaced by the Facebbok App's name and photo.

How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

I have solved the first part here [Posting comment to Facebook from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873608/posting-comment-to-facebook-from-javascript)

the second part is still not solved yet (writing the comment back to the facebook page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I have managed to solve this.

find the answer here

[Posting comment to Facebook from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873608/posting-comment-to-facebook-from-javascript)